# Cannot Start Up Rails 4 Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, startup

Getting this when I attempt to run "rails s"

```
/Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/digest/sha1.bundle
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:152:in `definition'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:115:in `setup'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/JustinLonas/projects/gohobbyist/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You're going to want to include your gemfile, as well as your requires.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this issue. I reinstalled homebrew and downloaded the yosemite CLI tools and everything just worked after that.